# Osmosis not working with mapfilewriter plugin

Tags: openstreetmap

I've recently downloaded Osmosis to convert .osm.pbf files to .map files. I'm using Windows 7 for this application. I've downloaded the latest [zip file](http://bretth.dev.openstreetmap.org/osmosis-build/osmosis-latest.zip) from their system and placed the mapfilewriter jar files into the /lib/default/ folder. However, I keep receiving this error when I run this statement in the .bat file:

```
osmosis --read-pbf file=taiwanlatest.osm.pbf --mapfile-writer file=helloworld.map

Mar 19, 2013 7:34:49 PM org.openstreetmap.osmosis.core.Osmosis run
INFO: Osmosis Version 0.42
Mar 19, 2013 7:34:49 PM org.openstreetmap.osmosis.core.Osmosis run
INFO: Preparing pipeline.
Mar 19, 2013 7:34:50 PM org.mapsforge.map.writer.osmosis.MapFileWriterTask <init>
INFO: mapfile-writer version: mapsforge-map-writer-0.3.0
Mar 19, 2013 7:34:50 PM org.mapsforge.map.writer.osmosis.MapFileWriterTask <init>
INFO: mapfile format specification version: 3
Mar 19, 2013 7:34:50 PM org.openstreetmap.osmosis.core.Osmosis run
INFO: Launching pipeline execution.
Mar 19, 2013 7:34:50 PM org.openstreetmap.osmosis.core.Osmosis run
INFO: Pipeline executing, waiting for completion.
Mar 19, 2013 7:34:50 PM org.openstreetmap.osmosis.core.pipeline.common.ActiveTaskManager waitForCompletion
SEVERE: Thread for task 1-read-pbf failed
java.lang.AbstractMethodError: org.mapsforge.map.writer.osmosis.MapFileWriterTas
k.initialize(Ljava/util/Map;)V
        at crosby.binary.osmosis.OsmosisReader.run(OsmosisReader.java:43)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)

Mar 19, 2013 7:34:50 PM org.openstreetmap.osmosis.core.Osmosis main
SEVERE: Execution aborted.
org.openstreetmap.osmosis.core.OsmosisRuntimeException: One or more tasks failed
.
        at org.openstreetmap.osmosis.core.pipeline.common.Pipeline.waitForComple
tion(Pipeline.java:146)
        at org.openstreetmap.osmosis.core.Osmosis.run(Osmosis.java:92)
        at org.openstreetmap.osmosis.core.Osmosis.main(Osmosis.java:37)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.
java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAcces
sorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchStandard(Laun
cher.java:329)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.jav
a:239)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(La
uncher.java:409)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:
352)
        at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:47)
```

I've read up and it seems that this occurs due to the osmosis itself, and that I have to use a lower version's osmosis. I've tried to use Osmosis version 0.40 and I've gotten this error when I run the .bat file:

```
Error: Could not find or load main class org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher
```

Where exactly did I go wrong?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

After much trial and error, I finally made it work by downloading Osmosis version 0.40.1 [here](http://bretth.dev.openstreetmap.org/osmosis-build/).

In addition, I've added 4 jar files in the /lib/default folder:

1. [mapsforge-map-writer-0.3.0-jar-with-dependencies.jar](https://code.google.com/p/mapsforge/downloads/detail?name=mapsforge-map-writer-0.3.0-jar-with-dependencies.jar&can=2&q=)
2. [mapsforge-map-0.3.0-jar-with-dependencies.jar](https://code.google.com/p/mapsforge/downloads/detail?name=mapsforge-map-0.3.0-jar-with-dependencies.jar&can=2&q=)
3. [trove-3.0.3.zip](http://nchc.dl.sourceforge.net/project/trove4j/trove/3.0.3/trove-3.0.3.zip)
4. [jts-1.8.jar](http://mirrors.ibiblio.org/maven2/com/vividsolutions/jts/1.8/jts-1.8.jar)

After which, i created a new conf file named "osmosis-plugins.conf" and added a line " org.mapsforge.map.writer.osmosis.MapFileWriterPluginLoader" in it.

After doing these steps, Osmosis finally works (though I'm not sure if this is the most correct way of doing it).

However, I still don't really understand why the latest version of Osmosis does not work.

Hope this can help those who faced a similar problem as me!

Comment: Thanks! Also, • make sure to get version 0.40.1 (easy to miss and get 0.41 instead); • the first 2 jars seemed enough for me; • the conf file should go in the config subfolder; • use `--used-node idTrackerType=Dynamic` and/or `type=hd` and/or `JAVACMD_OPTIONS=-Xmx1536M` if [memory](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Osmosis/Tuning#Memory) is a problem…

Comment: Commenting for posterity - Its important to use the older version of mapsforge-map-writer and mapsforge-map. I tried with the latest 0.16.0 and it doesnt work with that. I could not find 0.3.0 either, so I used the oldest one I could find 0.4.1 which you can download here - https://search.maven.org/artifact/org.mapsforge/mapsforge-map-writer/0.4.1/jar
https://search.maven.org/artifact/org.mapsforge/mapsforge-map/0.4.1/jar

Answer (score 2):

Bumped into this problem as well and here's my solution to it:

1. Download the `mapsforge-map-writer` jar file (the one with
   dependencies) from https://search.maven.org/search?q=mapsforge-map
2. Put the downloaded jar file into my `osmosis/lib/default` directory
3. Open up cmd, cd to where my osmosis is located and run a `--mapfile-writer` command.

Hope this helps!

Comment: This solution worked. For anyone who need another place to download, I downloaded it from https://oss.sonatype.org/#nexus-search;gav~org.mapsforge~mapsforge-map-writer~~~~kw,versionexpand